# Add one more element to multi dimensional array in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

A method is returning a 2-dimensional array in java. I want to add one more element to it. Not sure of the syntax of how to copy it to another new 2-d array& add one more element. Anyone have idea?

```
String arr[][]=getTwoDArray();
```

Now I want to add one more row to it. Something like this

```
String newArr[][] = new String[arr.length+1][];
arr[length+1][0]= {"car"};
```

### Any idea?

Comment: You can't resize arrays: their size is fixed at creation time. You can only create a new array and copy the contents in; you can do this conveniently using [`Arrays.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(T[],%20int)).

Comment: That´s what a [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), in this case a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html), would be there for

Answer (score 5):

You can't resize arrays: their size is fixed at creation time.

You can only create a new array and copy the contents in; you can do this conveniently using [`Arrays.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(T[],%20int)) (*):

```
String newArr[][] = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length + 1);
// Note that newArr[arr.length] is currently null.
newArr[arr.length] = new String[] { "car" };
```

However, as pointed out by @KevinEsche in his comment on the question, you might find an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) (or maybe some other kind of `List`) more convenient to use: although this is also backed by an array, and needs to resize that array occasionally, it hides the details from you.

---

(*) The gotcha here is that `Arrays.copyOf` performs a *shallow copy* of `arr`, so any changes to the elements of `arr[i]` will be reflected in the elements of `newArr[i]` (for `0 <= i < arr.length`). Should you need it, you can make a deep copy by looping over the elements of `arr`, calling `Arrays.copyOf` on each.

```
String newArr[][] = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length + 1);
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
  newArr[i] = Arrays.copyOf(arr[i], arr[i].length);
}
// ...
```